# What does “chemical Mickey” that drives a man to love-making mean?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I happened to read an old article about the mechanics of “human Love” which appeared in TIME magazine (Jan. 28, 2008) under the title, “The science of romance: Why we love,” and was drawn to the word, “Chemical Mickey” in the following sentence:

> “At the moment of a kiss, there's a rich and complicated exchange of
>   postural, physical and chemical information," says (psychologist
>   Gordon) Gallup. "There are hardwired mechanisms that process all this.
>   What's more, every kiss may also carry a **chemical Mickey**, slipped in
>   by the male. Though testosterone is found in higher concentrations in
>   men than in women, it is present in both genders and is critical in
>   maintaining arousal states.”
>   http://www.time.com/time/magazine/article/0,9171,1704672,00.html

I noticed that ABC News (Jan. 1, 2008) also picked up the similar research by incorporating the same word into the news;

> “The man is sort of slipping a **chemical mickey** that acts as an
>   aphrodisiac on the woman," Kluger said. That kiss could potentially
>   determine whether a couple's genes are compatible enough to produce a
>   healthy offspring.”

http://abcnews.go.com/GMA/OnCall/story?id=4147929&page=1

What does “Chemical Mickey” mean? Is the word, Mickey used as a metonym of a mysterious or powerful substance?

Comment: It is a very strange thing to say, as all Mickeys are chemical, not in the sense of "everything made of chemicals", but in the stronger sense of synthetic and artificial (and, moreover, biological signals are not).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ordinarily, *[mickey](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Mickey#Noun)* in the context of someone being drugged refers to a  “a beverage, usually alcoholic, that has been drugged”, ie, a *[Mickey Finn](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Mickey_Finn)*.  Wiktionary says the term is “Probably named for the manager and bartender of a Chicago establishment, the Lone Star Saloon and Palm Garden Restaurant, which operated from 1896 to 1903, who was accused of using "knockout drops" to incapacitate and rob some of his customers”.

The article's form,   “a chemical mickey”, probably was intended to suggest a pheromonal or hormonal effect, as opposed to the effect of an actual drink.

Comment: Original Mickey Finn consisted of solution of chloral hydrate in alcohol; also called knockout drops: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chloral_hydrate

Answer (score 5):

It's actually a form of [***slipping a mickey***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mickey_Finn_%28drugs%29). From [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/slip+a+mickey):

> to secretly put a [Mickey Finn](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Mickey%20Finn) in someone's alcoholic drink. (This drug either makes the victim pass out or causes immediate diarrhea.) :  *Somebody slipped Marlowe a Mickey and sent him into action.*

In this case, it means that the kiss carries a chemical pheromone that affects the behavior of the other individual in a manner similar to a drug. Unlike the original phrase, it does not imply intentionality.

Comment: p.w.s.g, so "someone had slipped a mickey in their tea" could be wrong because *tea* doesn't carry  chemical pheromone?

Comment: @Carlo_R. There's nothing wrong with *someone had slipped a mickey in their tea*--it would mean surreptitiously passing a drug into their drink. My point is that in **this context** *slipping a chemical mickey* is referring to pheremones.

Comment: I'm more curious about what sort of action Marlowe was sent into!  Whoever wrote that example sentence didn't have a very good grasp on the concept, I think - I believe it should have been *Somebody slipped Marlowe a Mickey and put him out of action.*

Comment: @MT_Head In a broader context, I believe the phase can be used to describe a drug that induces any kind of action the target would not otherwise do, but all the references I found cited this narrow meaning.

Comment: I guess, but I've mostly heard it in the knockout context - possibly with memory loss. I don't think I've heard of a 'Mickey' that causes diarrhea; not saying that's wrong, just a much less common usage.